# Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-assembly

I am using NUnit to test one functionality where I need to load XML file to object. The XML file is in location of the Console Application.

I have Following method where configuration will be read :

```
public string GetConfiguration(TempFlexProcessor processor)
{
    var exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    var configPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(exePath), "configuration");
    var configFile = string.Format(@"{0}.xml", processor.GetType().Name);
}
```

Now in my NUnit Test I have test method where I test GetConfiguration :

```
[Test]
    public void TempFlexProcessorExecuteTest()
    {
        #region Given


        #endregion

        #region When

        var tempFlexProcessor = new TempFlexProcessor();
        var actual = tempFlexProcessor.GetConfiguration(tempFlexProcessor);

        #endregion

        Assert.AreEqual("path of the file", actual);
    }
```

But System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is null, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead of `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that NUnit is running your tests in a different AppDomain, but without using `ExecuteAssembly`. From the [documentation for `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets the process executable in the default application domain. In other application domains, this is the first executable that was executed by `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly`.

It's not clear which assembly you really want to get - even if this *did* return something "appropriate" for NUnit, that's likely to be the NUnit executable, which would be well away from any configuration directories you happen to have.

Basically, I think that you should *at least* provide an alternative way of specifying the configuration directory - and you *might* want to reconsider whether using `GetEntryAssembly` is a good idea anyway. (Aside from anything else, it's slightly odd that you're calling `GetConfiguration` on a processor and passing in another processor... that may be suitable for your design, but it's at least somewhat unusual, given that in your test case you're passing in a reference to the same object.)

Comment: The GetConfiguration Method is in Console Application Class TempFlexProcessor and basically when I am trying to call GetConfiguration from NUnit it looks for Nunit Executable Assembly. Even though I get the Assembly of the TemplFlexProcessor, I get some temp folder path.

Comment: @MilindChavan: I thought you said it was returning `null`? That's not the same as finding the NUnit executable assembly... as for the temp folder path, that's presumably because of the way you're running NUnit. You can configure it to either copy the assemblies it's going to test or not. Perhaps you should use the *current* directory? I believe the current directory is usually left as the one containing the original test assembly.